# How to click a tab button

Tags: javascript, watir

I have a JavaScript page in which there is a table row containing 4 horizontal buttons as tab menu.

How to click particular button in a row?

I tried with

```
$ie.div(:id, 'tab4').click
```

and

```
$ie.row(:text, 'tab4').cell(:index, 2)
```

but this does not work.

Comment: What javascript framework (if any) are you using? Can we have some sample code from your tabs HTML?

Comment: Please post sample HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which javascript framework you are using, but if it's anything like jquery, then click would be a function call.

```
$ie.div(:id, 'tab4').click()
```